# JUnit @DisplayName not working in jenkins report

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins, junit5

I have project with JUnit5 and I use `@DisplayName` for each methods in the test classes.
When I run the test case in eclipse I am able to see the report generated with the given name in `@DisplayName`

When I tested it in jenkins it taken the actual method name to display.
But I need @DisplayName to be shown.

the plugin used in jenkins for junit test report -> publish junit test result report

[Eclipse test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFRZT.png)

[Jenkins test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvQIR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Input parameter site Id should have a non-empty default value.